# Wagtail removes the accented chars but should maintain it

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm working with Wagtail in a project in PT-BR and when I'm typing characters like an ã or an é they're removed from the RichTextBlock of a StreamField.

Until here I've tried to add the pt-br langague in WAGTAIL_CONTENT_LANGUAGES and LANGUAGES of settings.py but the problem remains.

PS: When I'm using TextField the problem doesn't occurs.

PS²: When text is pasted everything goes well.

Gif of problem:

[image]

Comment: That's probably a bug in the frontend rich-text editor. Can you paste in an ã? Does it disappear then?

Comment: The editor seems to be https://www.draftail.org/ – does it exhibit the same issue in that demo?

Comment: @AKX you're right, I got the same problem on [drafttail.org](https://drafttail.org).

Comment: Please report the bug in the Draftail project then – they'll know how to help better than I can. https://github.com/springload/draftail/issues (If you like, you can CC me in the issue, my GitHub handle is @akx).

Comment: @AKX I saw on drafttail's github there is a issue opened relating this topic to the firefox only. I've tested and works well in the Chrome and the Vivaldi browsers. The original issue is [https://github.com/springload/draftail/issues/447](https://github.com/springload/draftail/issues/447).